# asp.net fileupload control and file name

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

i'm using the asp.net file upload control. What i'd like to be able to do is upload the and save it on the server as a  different name.  Can i do this or do i need to upload first and then figure out how to rename it once it's on the server.  wondering what my options are.
thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
FileUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.saveas.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should just save the file with the required name as it is shown in the MSDN:

[Uploading Files in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in the file name you want and pass it to the SaveAs method like...

Suppose you want to store your file in the `UserFiles` Folder that is on the root of your website:

```
FileUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.Mappath("~/UserFiles/") + "NewFileName");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (FileUpload.HasFile)
{
     string Prename = "PavanKumar";               
     string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
     disp.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Admin/") + Prename +ext);
}
```

Comment: Just Get the Extension and add it to the Required filename You Required and Its Done